# Adding text manually at the end of the webpage in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to add some text to the `UIWebView`.

This web view is already loaded with a link. My intension is to add few lines of text at the

end of the page. The scrolling should be include for my text also.

The text i have inserted should appear to the user as a part of webpage only.

I tried this code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.activeElement;" 

"field.value='%@';",testLbl.text]; 

[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What specific problem are you having?

Comment: @Abizern yes i tried.NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.activeElement;" "field.value='%@';",testLbl.text];
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];

Comment: and few other ways to solve my problem

Comment: It helps if you add this information to your actual question.

Comment: @RajugoudBingi it worked for you??

Comment: @BulletRaja yes friend. It worked like a charm

Comment: then plz accept the answer bro by checking so others may also see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
 {
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height, 320, 50)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[label setText:@"copyright company name"];
[webView.scrollView addSubview:label];
[webView.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height+50)];
}
```